# IKVM converted Java objects' attributes are not initialized

Tags: java, c#, ikvm

I converted a Java .jar to a C# .dll library with IKVM, and everything worked well except for one thing: When I create an Instance of my Java class all of it's attributes are 0 or null (at least the debug view says so), except the one that is initialized first. I use an init() method that contains an AudioInputStream, and I think that it is the Problem, but I don't get any exceptions until I try to reference the Objects attributes.
I think so, beacause the one attribute that isn't null is initialized before, and after using the stream there are no console outputs any more (there should be some as you can see in the method).

I'm not an expert in c# or IKVM and I just don't know what to do now ...

That's the Code of the init() method:

```
    public void init(String s) {
    System.out.println("Loading file "+s);
    try {           
        File f = new File(s);
        file = f;
        AudioInputStream dais =
            AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f)));
        AudioFormat baseFormat = dais.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodeFormat = new AudioFormat(
            AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,//Encoding
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(),     //Samplerate
            16,                             //SampleSizeinBits (not compatible with 32bit on Windows)
            baseFormat.getChannels(),       // Channels
            baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,   // FrameSize
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(),     // FramRate
            false
        );
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodeFormat, dais); 
        System.out.println("Successfully loaded "+s);

        numChannels = baseFormat.getChannels();
        System.out.println("   Numchannels "+numChannels+"   The number of channels");

        frameLength = (int) ais.getFrameLength();
        System.out.println("   Framelength "+frameLength+"   The number frames for the whole file");
        frameSize = (int) baseFormat.getFrameSize();
        System.out.println("   Framesize "+frameSize+"   The number of bYtes per Frame");
        frameRate = (int) baseFormat.getFrameRate();
        System.out.println("   Framerate "+frameRate+"      The number of frames per second in hz");
        sampleRate = (int) baseFormat.getSampleRate();
        System.out.println("   Samplerate "+sampleRate+"   The number of samples per second in hz");
        sampleSize = (int) baseFormat.getSampleSizeInBits();
        System.out.println("   Samplesize(bit) "+sampleSize+"   The number of bits per sample");
        System.out.println("   Samplesize(byte) "+sampleSize/8+"   The number of bytes per sample");

        byte[] bytes = new byte[frameLength*frameSize];

        try {
            ais.read(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        int[][] toReturn = new int[numChannels][frameLength];

        int sampleIndex = 0;//like framepos
        for (int t = 0; t < bytes.length;) {                
            for (int channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++) {
                if(sampleSize == 16){
                    int low = (int) bytes[t];
                    t++;
                    int high = (int) bytes[t];
                    t++;
                    int sample = getSixteenBitSample(high, low);
                    toReturn[channel][sampleIndex] = sample;
                }else if(sampleSize == 32){
                    int low = (int) bytes[t];
                    t++;
                    int lower = (int) bytes[t];
                    t++;
                    int higher = (int) bytes[t];
                    t++;
                    int high = (int) bytes[t];
                    t++;
                    int sample = getThirtyTwoBitSample(high,higher,lower, low);
                    toReturn[channel][sampleIndex] = sample;
                }
            }
            sampleIndex++;
        }


        channels = new Channel[numChannels];
        for(int i = 0; i < channels.length; i++){
            channels[i] = new Channel(toReturn[i]);
        }

        samples = toReturn;

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;

}
```

Comment: EDIT: Apparently the javax.sound package is just not implemented in IKVM ... what leads to another question: is there any way how I could include this package manually ?